# Haskell tcp server, fd is too big error

Tags: sockets, haskell, tcp

I've been trying to write a Haskell server for a Go client. For the Haskell TCP server I'm simply using `Network.Socket`. Whenever I try to run `hWaitForInput`, I am getting this error:

```
fdReady: fd is too big.
```

Here is the server code -

```
connHandler :: (Socket, SockAddr) -> IO()
connHandler (sock, _) = do
  putStrLn "Starting Handler"
  handle <- socketToHandle sock ReadWriteMode
  hSetBuffering handle LineBuffering
  hPutStrLn handle "Hello Client!"
  putStrLn "Waiting for Input"
  success <- hWaitForInput handle (1000*10)
  putStrLn "Wait done"
  if success
      then do
          putStrLn "Client timed out"
      else do
          msg <- hGetLine handle
          putStrLn msg
  hClose handle
```

The Go client is receiving and printing the server's message("Hello Client!") but the haskell server throws the error right after printing "Waiting for Input"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong.  The specific error message you're seeing only shows up with GHC >=8.0.2 running on Windows and represents a bug/limitation in an internal GHC function `fdReady` that they've tried to address on non-Windows architectures but have left unfixed on Windows.  (Don't feel too jealous, though -- the "fix" on non-Windows architectures is currently broken and crashes, too.)  Trying an earlier version of GHC probably wouldn't help -- it would still cause an error, but the error message would be different.

Here's the problem: on Windows, the internal function `fdReady` uses the `select()` system call to poll file descriptors for sockets, and `select` is limited to a certain maximum numerical value for the file descriptors it can poll.  It looks like the Windows default for this value is quite low (64) but can be increased at compile time (the time *GHC* is compiled, unfortunately, not the time when GHC compiles your program).

If you add the line:

```
hShow handle >>= putStrLn
```

just before your `hWaitForInput`, you should see some debug info printed for the socket, including something like `loc=<socket: nnn>` where `nnn` is the file descriptor.  This may help you verify that you're seeing a file descriptor greater than 64 that's causing the problem.

If this is the case, I would suggest filing a GHC bug to see if you can get it fixed.

Comment: I just [opened a bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14530#ticket). Let's see what happens...

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative/workaround, you could try reading a line in one thread and a timer in another thread.

```
putStrLn "Waiting for Input"
msgMVar <- newEmptyMVar
tid <- forkIO $ hGetLine handle >>= putMVar msgMVar
maybeExn <- waitTimeout tid (1000*10)
case maybeExn of
    Nothing -> do
        killThread tid
        putStrLn "Client timed out"
    Just (Just _) ->
        putStrLn "Exception"
    _ -> do
        msg <- takeMVar msgMVar
        putStrLn msg
hClose handle
```

This does have different behavior (can time out in the middle of reading a line) than your code (never times out if a single byte can be read, even if the line is not complete), though.

Comment: I wonder if killing the thread that is doing the `hGetLine` will work on Windows. I currently cannot do this, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507586/killing-a-thread-waiting-on-hgetline-from-a-socket-windows).